# Node API Facebook Auth from a mobile

Tags: node.js, facebook, api

I found plenty of tutorial about how to setup FB login with NodeJS when Node is responsable of the rendering of the page like with Passport and an engine like PUG.

But what about microservice where the API is agnostic of the front ? Like  an API for a mobile app.

The smartphone have to handle the authorisation from facebook to let my app to access his profile, then how do I validate the bunch of data the device will send back to the API to accept or not the login process and access to the protected route ?

Do I have to register my API and the Apps (iOS/Android) to FB ?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to register my API and the Apps (iOS/Android) to FB ?

Yes You'll need to register your API on Facebook

You can do it from https://developers.facebook.com